# Python Watchdog - How to only view when files are created?

Tags: python, python-watchdog

From the [Watchdog Quickstart](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html), I can see all events such as when a folder is modified, a file deleted, a file created, etc. However, I only want to see when a file has been created. What do I have to change to only see created files?

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create your own event handler class based on `FileSystemEventHandler`. You would override the `on_created` method to process the event when received.

Comment: But wouldn't the other events still trigger?

Comment: A base `FileSystemEventHandler` object won't do anything in particular. Therefore if you don't override the methods for the other events they will do their default action (that is, nothing).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at `watchdog.events` LoggingEventHandler. Nothing in the code that you've attached has anything to do with tracking specific filesystem actions except for starting the LoggingEventHandler module, which I can assume handles all filesystem events?

Comment: Well, that code is straight from the quickstart. My question is how can I ignore all actions except for creation of files?